# Android 5 RecyclerView like Gmail

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design, android-recyclerview

I was playing with RecyclerView, and I found that there not much document on how to play with it

I see from the document that the GMail application is using RecyclerView, but in the application it has lots of features that a normal RecyclerView doesnt support:

There is a screenshot from it

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Features:

1. List item highlight when onTouch
2. Swipe left/right to delete

May I know how to implement these features?

I found there is a discussion on how to implement OnClickListener, (thou these solution is quite sluggish, because it constantly checks for the list item region)

[RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

But, if you compare it with the Gmail application, it is fast and fluid!

May I know how can I implement the 2 features above? How do they do it? are they using Recyclerview or ListView?

I am sure I could implement those features using ListView, but I have no idea how to implement them using Recyclerview.

Answer (score 6):

Swipe left/right can be performed that way:
[Swipe with ItemTouchHelper - jmcdale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293960/swipe-to-dismiss-for-recyclerview/30601554#30601554)

SwipeToDismiss available out of the box from Android support library.

1. Add 'recyclerview-v7:22.2.+' dependence to build.gradle:

   `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'`
2. Add remove method to your RecyclerView.Adapter implementation:

   ```
   public class ExampleAdapter extends Adapter<ExampleItem> {
       [...]
       public void remove(int position) {
           list.remove(position);
           notifyItemRemoved(position);
       }

   }
   ```
3. Use ItemTouchHelper and ItemTouchHelper.Callback:

   ```
   ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

       @Override
       public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            //Remove swiped item
            adapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())
       }

       @Override
       public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
           //Available drag and drop directions
           int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
           //Available swipe directions
           int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
           return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
       }

       //Disable or Enable drag and drop by long press
       @Override
       public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
           //return false;
           return true;
       }

       //Disable or Enable swiping
       @Override
       public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
           //return false;
           return true;
       }

   };

   ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
   ```
4. Attach ItemTouchHelper to RecyclerView

   ```
   itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
   ```

Another useful link: [Drag and swipe with recyclerView](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: gmail longpress contextual action mode android pleasae provide some help how tod esign and handle gmail longpress and deleted