# How to get View in RecyclerView.Adapter for Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing **Swipe** and Drag in `RecyclerView` through the help of this [article](http://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf). On removing the item I want to show a `SnackBar` but showing `SnackBar`  needs View.  I don't know how to get `View` inside the function of a `RecyclerAdapter`.

**My Code:**

```
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        notes.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        /* Show SnackBar */
    }
```

Edit: My question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293960/swipe-to-dismiss-for-recyclerview). I am not having any problem in implementing SwipetoDismiss.I have successfully implemented it. But I want to show a SnackBar so that user can be notfied and Undo. I am having problem in showing SnackBar not in implementing onSwiped().

Comment: Create an interface to pass in view + an integer, use is it as a callback by implementing in your activity or fragment.

Comment: I have modified the interface which I am implementing through RecyclerAdapter. But for callback only ItemTouchHelper.Callback can be used. To do Swipe, we have to Override onSwiped method in this callback

Comment: Just look at my working example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swipe to Dismiss for RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293960/swipe-to-dismiss-for-recyclerview)

Comment: not remotely related to that question @JaredBurrows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify your method and pass `RecyclerView` as Parameter so you will get view

```
public void onItemDismiss(int position,RecyclerView rv) {
        notes.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        /* Show SnackBar */
        Snackbar.make(rv, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

```
private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;
private final RecyclerView rv;
public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter,RecyclerView rv) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
    this.rv=rv;
}
```

And then pass

```
 @Override
    public void onSwiped(ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),rv);
    }
```

Comment: Shows error on 'onSwiped' method on 'SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback'

Comment: onItemDismiss (int, RecyclerView) in ItemTouchHelper cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: In onSwiped() ViewHolder is passed as parameter. Is there a way to get View through ViewHolder?

Comment: can you post code where you are calling `onSwiped()`, you must pass position and rv as parameter

Comment: I am calling it in SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback. You can see it in the article. My implementation is same.

Comment: Here is the link : https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/79fa9c8ed00f64af690b#file-simpleitemtouchhelpercallback-java

Comment: You must call like this ` mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), recyclerview );`

Comment: Have already done that but in onSwiped(), there is no parameter of RecylerView.

Comment: You must pass from you activity where you define adapter and recyclerview , where you assigned adapter to recyclerview.

Comment: you can modify you constructor as ` public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter,RecyclerVIew rv) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82557/discussion-between-nilesh-and-mmohits).

Answer (score 1):

you can use Android's content view by typecasting your context

```
Activity activity=(Activity) context;
```

and use in snackbar to get view

```
Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Hello",BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG).show
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the accepted answer? Are there benefits to this approach? Does it take advantage of new syntax, or solve any particular limitations?

Comment: This is just an alternative method for getting view in RecylerView.Adapter .