# How to add swipe functionality on Android CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener, android-cardview

I have a single CardView that contains two TextViews and two ImageViews. I want to be able to swipe left and right to "dismiss". I actually want swipe right to send an Intent but that can be done later. For now, I want to be able to dismiss the CardView by swiping left or right. I also want the animation of swiping.

I tried using [`romannurik's SwipeDismissTouchListener`](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.java) but the CardView does not respond to swiping.

If anyone has a better solution than `romannurik's` custom listener, please share.

**Here's my CardView layout:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/generate"
    map:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
    map:cardElevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:id="@+id/restaurantContainer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_75sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_75sdp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_75sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/categories"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                map:cameraZoom="14"
                map:liteMode="true"
                map:mapType="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**How I setup the SwipeDismissTouchListener:**

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout;
CardView restaurantCardView;

...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        restaurantCardView = (CardView) rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.restaurantContainer);

        restaurantCardView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDismissTouchListener(restaurantCardView, null, new SwipeDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public boolean canDismiss(Object token) {
                Log.d("Chris", "canDismiss() called with: " + "token = [" + token + "]");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(View view, Object token) {
                Log.d("Chris", "onDismiss() called with: " + "view = [" + view + "], token = [" + token + "]");
            }
        }));
    ....

    return rootLayout;
```

I am able to see the log from `canDismiss(...)` but not from `onDismiss(...)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to put it inside `RecyclerView` (and your `CardView` as the only item there)

Then, use `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to `itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);`

It will give you animations and in

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
}
```

you can specify particular action based on the swipe direction.

See full instruction here: [Swipe to Dismiss for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30601554/1658267)

Also, you'll have to disable vertical scroll in `RecyclerView`:

```
public class UnscrollableLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    public UnscrollableLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
}

.....

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new UnscrollableLinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RestaurantCardAdapter());
```

Otherwise - once you'll try to scroll up or down - you'd see `RecyclerView`'s end-of-list animations.

**Upd:**

Here's `RecyclerView.Adapter` I used for test:

```
private class RestaurantCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RestaurantViewHolder(new RestaurantCard(parent.getContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    private class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RestaurantViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

`RestaurantCard` - is just a custom `View` (extends `CardView` in our case):

```
public class RestaurantCard extends CardView {
    public RestaurantCard(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public RestaurantCard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context){
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card, this);
        // ImageView imageView = (ImageView)getView.findViewById(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate your detailed answer. I have a question: since I am only using one CardView, what is the best way to create the `RestaurantCardAdapter`? All the examples online are for lists. Is there anything that I should be doing specifically? I just don't want to get stuck somewhere and spend my time trying to fix stupid mistakes haha.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi I've updated the answer with Adapter & ViewHolder I used for testing the idea. Good luck! Any questions - just ask

Comment: I am having trouble with `onCreateViewHolder(...)`. I think we need to inflate a view based on what I've seen online. Because in `onBindViewHolder(...)`, my `RestaurantViewHolder`'s reference to the `TextViews` and `ImageViews` are `null`. So there has to be something with the views that we're missing.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi I added RestaurantCard class in the answer. Don't do anything with ViewHolder, just reuse my Adapter & ViewHolder as it is.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your help! Everything's up and running.

Comment: @Konstantin Loginov  I see that the set up attaches the ItemTouchHelper object to the RecycerView.  Is there a way to attach the object to a single CardView shown in a Detail Activity (rather than the RecyclerView Activity)?