# How do i extend cardview and pass it as the only item inside Recyclerview?

Tags: android, class, android-recyclerview, extend, android-cardview

Hi i am new to android i was trying to make the swipe to dismiss feature with `cardview` & `Recyclerview` using `itemtouchhelper.callback` so i need to pass `cardview` as the only item in `RecyclerView` as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620840/how-to-add-swipe-functionality-on-android-cardview) mentioned but i don't know how to extend the `cardView` to make customview?

cardStack

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;


public class CardStack extends CardView {
  private int image;


    public CardStack(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public CardStack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public CardStack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void initialize(Context context){
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,this);
        //What to do here?
    }
```

card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.stocks.android.cardviewobjectswipefeaturestocks.CardStack
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/card1" />

    </com.stocks.android.cardviewobjectswipefeaturestocks.CardStack>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you want to extend your `CardView` its already a `ViewGroup` you can add custom views in there

Comment: so that i could make the whole cardView as a single item and pass it to recyclerview ? can i do that without creating a customview?

Comment: See the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Make a layout file, with parent as CardView. 
I`ve made a row_list_item.xml which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/OFF_WHITE"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
.........
</LinearLayout>
</CardView>
```

Then inside your adapter pass it to the  adapter this way:

```
  @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_list_item, parent, false));
    }
```

And you're done. Kudos!