# Material Design CardView Swipe Like Animation - Is there any material on how to?

Tags: android, animation, material-design, android-cardview

I have been trying for a while to find any material on how to create the below animation for the material CardView, but i havent been able to find anything. So does anybody know any library or somewhere that i can read about?

More specificly, i am trying to recreate the animation with the background color expanding from the heart icon.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add swipe functionality on Android CardView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620840/how-to-add-swipe-functionality-on-android-cardview)

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf as far as i can see this is only the dismiss function, i am looking for the specific animation with the background color expanding from the heart.

Comment: Look at this: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/ You'll need to tweak the linked tutorial into using CardViews. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already created this, however i have no clue on how to implement the animation from the gif above, thanks for the help though.

Comment: "...I already created this, however i have no clue on how to implement the animation" Go through the second link and see what you can learn from it. Try to adapt it for card views and if you run into any problems feel free to post a new question with code, screenshots and layouts so that your problem can be better addressed.