# NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$3

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi I want to create swipe to delete on `RecyclerView` the result is a crash:

Look at the `build.gradle`, I imported all the libs requeired. In code I'm able to use `ItemTouchHelper` class but when i want to swipe an item it crashes.

`build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

CRASH:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$3
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper.select(ItemTouchHelper.java:608)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$2.onTouchEvent(ItemTouchHelper.java:389)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnItemTouch(RecyclerView.java:2519)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2662)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9300)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2771)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:67)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:67)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewR

Comment: `recyclerview-v7:25.3.1`

Comment: sorry , but updating to 25.3.1 doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faced with this problem several days ago.
In my case it was fixed by **updating all** `com.android.support:*` dependencies from 25.3.1 to **26.0.0**. And make sure they all using the same version.
Hope it will help someone.