# Simply Swipe any Normal Android View without third party library

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, swipe

I want to move any normal view in my app along with swipe.

I am able to detect swipe using **OnTouchListener** in **onTouch** method. But am **not able to move the view along with the swipe**.

I want to move the view along with the swipe.

I think so that something i need to implement inside onTouch method to move the view or item along with swipe, but what i don't know.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: see `ItemTouchHelper`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe to Dismiss for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293960/swipe-to-dismiss-for-recyclerview)

Comment: @azizbekian and @pskink it don't want to swipe it only for `RecyclerView` but also for `ListView` and any normal View.

Comment: so change your title to: "How to Simply Swipe items of ListView **and** RecyclerView **and** any normal View without third party library"

Comment: @pskink I made the changes to the question and made it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `view.setTranslationX(diffX)` for X coordinate and `view.setTranslationY(diffY)` for Y coordinate while its `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` under `onTouch()` method.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    float downX, downY, nowX, nowY, diffX, diffY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                downX = event.getRawX();
                downY = event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                nowX = event.getRawX();
                nowY = event.getRawY();

                diffX = nowX - downX;
                diffY = nowY - downY;

                v.setTranslationX(diffX);
                v.setTranslationY(diffY);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```